# Powershell Get-ADUser fails for Date properties due to invalid Win32 FileTime

Tags: powershell, active-directory, get-aduser

The below powershell command works for most of the accounts.

```
import-module activedirectory
Get-ADUser <account> -Properties *
```

For some accounts, I get following error

```
Get-ADUser : Not a valid Win32 FileTime.
Parameter name: fileTime
At line:4 char:1
+ Get-ADUser <account> -Properties AccountExpirationDate
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (<account>:ADUser) [Get-ADUser], ArgumentOutOfRangeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

I suspect it is because of empty (?) date property.

For valid accounts, it looks like this

```
AccountExpirationDate : 01/01/2030 00:00:00
```

Is there any way to still collect the information for these users, just excluding Date properties?

As there are hundreds of properties, I would prefer to avoid specifying which I need... unless it does not have impact on performance?

I tried the below which fails presumably due to select on failing query.

```
Get-ADUser <account> -Properties * | Select-Object -Property * | Where-Object { $_.AccountExpirationDate -ne $null}
```

Comment: What is throwing the `Not a valid Win32 FileTime` error ? The last statement shouldn't for sure. There is something you're not showing us.

Comment: Please copy and paste, as text, the error message as it appears in the console. `Get-ADUser` does not produce output JSON-like output. What really comes out?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon modified.

Comment: mm thats odd, what happens if you query `accountExpires` instead for that same user? `Get-ADUser <account> -Properties accountExpires`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon That works because data type is not  [DateTime], e.g. `accountExpires :133590744000000000`

Comment: I know its not, I wanted to see what value it had to make the cmdlet fail like that. `AccountExpirationDate` is basically a friendly property constructed by the cmdlet. You can query `accountExpires` instead and then convert it to `DateTime` using `[datetime]::FromFileTimeUtc`. i.e. `[datetime]::FromFileTimeUtc(133590744000000000)`

Comment: My problem is that query for all properties fails. I can select what I need or do conversions, but aim is to either select all but specific fields (without definition of all) or somehow ignore these errors.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `accountExpires` LDAP attribute has never been set (value 0) or if the attribute for the user has been set to 'Never Expires' (value 9223372036854775807)
In both cases, there will be no valid DateTime in the `AccountExpirationDate` property you need.

Also, you should not use `-Properties *` if you only need a few extra properties on top of the ones Get-ADUser returns by default, which are:
*DistinguishedName, Enabled, GivenName, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID, Surname, UserPrincipalName*

Try

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'Enabled -eq $true' -Properties AccountExpirationDate, accountExpires |
Where-Object { $_.accountExpires -gt 0 -and $_.accountExpires -ne 9223372036854775807 } |  # exclude users with account Never Expires
Select-Object Name, SamAccountName, AccountExpirationDate | 
Sort-Object AccountExpirationDate -Descending
```